# XQDT : where did Marklogic option go?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, marklogic

Hello Marklogic community,

I am trying to make some steps in learning and discovering Marklogic toolset.

I have installed the eclipse XQDT tools but now I fail to install the plugin for Marklogic...

In the install docs on the wiki I can see the Marklogic adapter in version 0.8xxx http://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT/Installation [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XQDT/Installation)

Any suggestions?

hugo

[image: available software]

Comment: ok i found a plugin on the ML site here:[link](http://developer.marklogic.com/eclipse/xqdt/milestone/latest/) but when i try to install this i get: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: MarkLogic XQDT Adapter Feature 0.7.0.v201001160647-17R-AkF7B77JBZFJF7 .....

Comment: if i stick to ML version 0.7 in get: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: XQuery Development Tools Feature 0.7.0.v201001121118-47Z-BgJ9E99OEhJOJ9 (org.eclipse.wst.xquery.feature.feature.group 0.7.0.v201001121118-47Z-BgJ9E99OEhJOJ9)
  Missing requirement: XQDT Launching Plug-in 0.7.0.v201003172320 (org.eclipse.wst.xquery.launching 0.7.0.v201003172320) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: XQuery Development Tools Feature 0.7.0 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read this http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/xqdt-setup ?

"The current version of XQDT from the Eclipse update site will not work with MarkLogic.  While this issue remains, kindly download a copy of XQDT from http://developer.marklogic.com/download/code/eclipse/xqdt-dropin.zip and unpack it into the dropins folder underneath Eclipse.  You should see the following hierarchy underneath the main Eclipse folder with the zip unpacked into the dropins folder."

Regards,

Emil

Answer (score 0):

So please check upfront which specific combination of MarkLogic with Eclipse and plugin should work. Two setup manuals can be found at http://developer.marklogic.com/media/mluc11-labs/eclipse-xqdt-setup/Eclipse-setup.pdf and http://java-development.wikispaces.com/file/view/eclipse-xqdt-setup.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for an old question: [mcrosier](https://github.com/mcrosier) is working on [updating XQDT for current versions of Eclipse and MarkLogic](https://github.com/mcrosier/ML-XQDT).